# Providing a template type of the same type as argument causes an error for rvalue reference function

Tags: c++, templates, rvalue-reference, rvalue, lvalue

I'm using a library with a templated function that takes an rvalue reference, and for clarity, I am explicitly stating the template type instead of relying inference. I noticed that when the template type matches the argument type and the argument is an lvalue, I get a compiler error. Please see the example below, where the error is reproduced in the 3rd case.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
void fnc(T &&value) {
  std::cout << value << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  int32_t var = 5;

  // Call with no template type and lvalue: OK
  fnc(var);

  // Call with different template type and lvalue: OK
  fnc<int16_t>(var);

  // Call with same template type and lvalue: ERROR
  // cannot bind rvalue reference of type ‘int&&’ to lvalue of type ‘int32_t’ {aka ‘int’}
  fnc<int32_t>(var);

  // Call with no template type and rvalue: OK
  fnc(5);

  // Call with different template type and rvalue: OK
  fnc<int16_t>(5);

  // Call with same template type and rvalue: OK
  fnc<int32_t>(5);

  return 0;
}
```

Note that on my machine, `cstdlib` introduces `typedef signed int int32_t` and `typedef signed short int16_t`.

Why does this happen, and how can I work around it? I'd like to continue to be explicit with template types for safety.

Comment: Interesting. Having said that, My general recommendation is, for your sanity, never help the template function and let it deduce the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your own experiment, `int16&&` can bind to a temporary `int16` converted from an `int32` l-value, but `int32&&` cannot bind to an actual `int32` l-value.

This has nothing to do with templates, see below:

```
void fnc16(int16_t&& value) {
  std::cout << value << std::endl;
}

void fnc32(int32_t&& value) {
  std::cout << value << std::endl;
}


int main() {
  int32_t var = 5;

  fnc16(var);  // OK

  fnc32(var);  // ERROR
}
```

https://godbolt.org/

These are the rules as strange as they look.

Note for example that you can make it work by, creating an rvalue

```
  fnc32(+var);  // OK now
```

It is hard to understand what you want to achieve by specifying the template for a function template call instead of letting it deduce it for you. (Deduction is how perfect-forwarding works).

In any case, if you insist on suppressing the deduction, you have to use the right template type that can bind to an l-value reference, that is:

```
  fnc<int32_t&>(var);
```

in your original code.

This is because reference collapsing: `"int32_t& &&" -> int32_t&`, which is correct for `var` (but not for `+var` now).

In fact, any qualified argument would probably work `<int32_t&>`, `<int32_t&&>`, `<int32_t const&>`, but not `<int32_t>`.

Comment: Thank you, I understand a little better now. I'm working with a device where bit size matters, and I want that to be explicit in the code so anyone looking at it knows exactly how many bits are being written. Depending on deduction could result in a case where a variable of the wrong size is written.

Comment: @Jacob, if you want people "know exactly how many bits are being written" don't use function overloading, name the functions differently `fun16`, `fun32`, at least in the interface.

Comment: this function is provided by a library, so I don't have control over that.

Comment: @Jacob, you can wrap it accordingly, for example `auto fun16(int16_t& i) {return fun<CarefulTypeGoesHere>(i);}`.